# How to choose SQL DDL type parameters?

Tags: sql, types

All the SQL dialects I've seen use to either allow or to require to specify an integer argument for some of the data types they support when defining a table. But I haven't managed to find any comprehensive information (at least for MySQL and SQLite) about what exactly do these numbers mean and how to chose them adequately...

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: INTEGER(11). When I've used Navicat (a GUI DB tool) to copy a database from MySQL (where I had used bare INT for integer columns), I've got the new SQLite database with integer columns defined as INTEGER(11). Why? Why not just INTEGER?

Comment: You might want to look into Liquibase to manage your schema definition in a DBMS-independent (and controllable) way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the notation like INT(11), VARCHAR(255), then normally it's the length of the values stored (or retrieved) from the table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-type-overview.html

There's an "M" in  parentheses after name of every type which supports it.

Also, keep in mind that these numbers may affect both storage and selection length. For example, if you define a column as VARCHAR(100), the actual space reserved for each value will still be 255. But the values you retrieve in SELECT will be trimmed down to 100 characters. And if you define a VARCHAR(256), then it reserves up to 65535 characters, if I remember correctly.

The same with INT(5). It still reserves space for storing values up to 2147483647 (max value for signed integers), but trims the input/output to 5 digits.

Comment: I know it is the length of the values, but I was not sure about how exatly is it measured. I used to suppose it is in bytes or some special units for INT. I don't want to constraint it then, all I want is to store a standard integer from -2147483648 to 2147483647 and unify my tables definition (use the same type declarations for different DBMSes) as far as possible. Can I use just INT or INTEGER for MySQL, SQLite3 and MS SQL Server or should I specify the length?

Comment: I don't think writing cross-DBMS DDLs is such a good idea anyway. You will definitely stumble into difficulties; sometimes you even want to use different types for different SQL implementations. I think that if  you want to make a cross-DBMS database deployment tool, you should create a utility for that. Investigate each type separately and decide in the code which one you should use for the type of DBMS you're currently working with.

Comment: But what about integers? Do you believe that `INT` means the same for MySQL, SQLite3 and MS SQL Server and I am not going to loose any data if I omit `(11)`?

Comment: For MySQL, if you don't specify the length, it will default to 11. I am not sure about another SQL dialects. That's why you'll have to try it yourself.

Comment: And if you really want to try making cross-DBMS DDL statements, you should definitely omit `(11)`.

Comment: Thanks. To make it clear, I am not going to write really "cross-DBMS DDL statements". There are going to be separate DDL scripts for different DBMSes (because I don't want to give up using indices and foreign keys where available), but I'd like my DDL to be as unified (using the same syntax) as possible without notable penalties.